# Security risk when exposing Facebook access_token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

I'm pulling a list of Facebook albums from a page using a GET url like so:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<page-id>/albums?access_token=<app-id>|<app-secret>`

Even though the page is public, apparently you have to provide an access_token to pull content. So, my question is, is this a huge security vulnerability by publicly displaying the app ID and the secret key in the browser? I'm using JavaScript, so I'm afraid that someone could just grab the app ID and the secret key and then use it to post spam to the account. Is that possible? Or am I forgetting about another security step that has to be taken in order to actually write using the API?

Comment: You should never expose tokens (that are not the user’s very own access token) in client-side code. Everyone can read them from there, and abuse them. The app access token allows a lot of app settings to be changed, and performing of other actions in the name of the app as well. You need to either make viewing the user login to your app, so that you can use their personal access token; or you need to move this code to the server side.

Comment: Cool, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks! Feel free to answer the question if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never expose tokens (that are not the user’s very own access token) in client-side code. Everyone can read them from there, and abuse them. The app access token allows a lot of app settings to be changed, and performing of other actions in the name of the app as well.

You need to either make viewing the user login to your app, so that you can use their personal access token; or you need to move this code to the server side.